# Assault by someone if i said hit me in my argument does that mean no crime

Tags: ontario

If you said come on hit me in an arguement and opponent hits you is it still a assault or consensual fight how can we determined the consent

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/15860/are-you-allowed-to-strike-a-person-if-they-say-you-can

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are you allowed to strike a person if they say you can?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/15860/are-you-allowed-to-strike-a-person-if-they-say-you-can)

Answer (score 2):

A person *can* consent to the application of *trivial* bodily harm. In that case, the intentional application of force is not assault, if is in fact what was consented to and limited to trivial bodily harm.

However, there can be no "consent between adults intentionally to apply force causing serious hurt or non-trivial bodily harm to each other in the course of a fist fight or brawl." See *R. v Jobidon*, [[1991] 2 S.C.R. 714](https://canlii.ca/t/1fskj).